# paste lines of string characters in raw text

Tags: regex, r

I work on raw textual data from a scanned catalog.
Here is an example:

```
ABADIE-LANDEL (Pierre) — 1920 — né à Paris. — 17, rue Campagne-Première   
ABOU (Albert) — 1930 — né à Marseille.  
 — 41, rue de Seine, 6e.  
ANGER (Jacques) — 1925 — né à Paris. — 33, rue Vineuse, 16e.  
ANTHONE (Armand) — 1908 — né à Paris. — 4, avenue Victor-Hugo  
 Rue des Tournelles
ANTRAL (Jean) — 1920
```

This is a list of names with occasional lines including address mentions.

The data is imported into R with:

```
readlines ("clipboard", encoding = " latin1 ")
```

- I am able to identify lines including  artist names in capital letters with different regex

`[A-ZÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝYÆO][A-ZÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝYÆO |']`

or  (ICU)

`[\p{Uppercase Letter}][\p{Uppercase Letter}|']`

- I am able to identify lines including artworks

^[0-9]+[\s][^bis]`

- I am able to extract artists names

`".+(?=- [0-9]{4})"`

or

`(.+)[0-9]{4}.+ # with backreference \1`

- For more data, here is a sample of data from a 1930 catalog:
  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nF3CQmZbDsCGKMp_OgZymxWIfoOx5xrNdTmDXZANwuc/edit?usp=sharing

I wish I could paste the pieces of adress substrings  but **My final goal** is to create a data.frame object structured as follows:

1st column: NAME artist and surname;
2nd column: supplements (address, nationality ...)
3rd columns: works or better ...
Column 3: 1 work
4th column 2 work, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you always have 4 fields? Can you split by `" — "`?

Comment: i am still not sure what you want to do. could you provide a minimal workable example of your data and an example of the desired output?

Comment: What is the output you hope to get from the above example? (Show with a code example pls)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract names and addresses from your records some of which may span across different lines.

One solution may be to exploit the fact that the character `—` works as a field separator. So assuming that the structure of your records is regular you could do:

(data is a variable holding your example string)

```
## Replace newlines with the separator character 
data <- gsub("\\n(\\s*—)?", " — ", data)

## Normalize space
data <- gsub("\\s+", " ", data)

## Now split by the separator character
tokens <- strsplit(data, "\\s—\\s")[[1]]
```

tokens now contains:

```
[1] "ABADIE-LANDEL (Pierre)"    "1920"                      "né à Paris."               "17, rue Campagne-Première" "ABOU (Albert)"
[6] "1930"                      "né à Marseille."           "41, rue de Seine, 6e."     "ANGER (Jacques)"           "1925"
[11] "né à Paris."               "33, rue Vineuse, 16e."     "ANTHONE (Armand)"          "1908"                      "né à Paris."
[16] "4, avenue Victor-Hugo"     "Rue des Tournelles"        "ANTRAL (Jean)"             "1920"
```

Each complete record should have 4 sequential indices in this vector but since there may be incomplete records we must work a little more.

We exploit the fact that people's names are all-capitals and follow a strict pattern. We get the indices of the names in `tokens` and then split `tokens` on those indices. Each subvector produced is now a complete record:

```
## Get the indices of names
idx <- which(grepl("^[A-Z-]+\\s\\(", tokens))

## Use the indices to partition tokens to subvectors
records <- list()

for (i in 1:length(idx)) {
    start <- idx[i]
    if (i == length(idx)) {
        stop <- length(tokens)
    }
    else {
        stop <- idx[i+1] - 1
    }

    records[[i]] <- tokens[start:stop]
}
```

Here is the final list of results:

```
[[1]]
[1] "ABADIE-LANDEL (Pierre)"    "1920"                      "né à Paris."               "17, rue Campagne-Première"

[[2]]
[1] "ABOU (Albert)"         "1930"                  "né à Marseille."       "41, rue de Seine, 6e."

[[3]]
[1] "ANGER (Jacques)"       "1925"                  "né à Paris."           "33, rue Vineuse, 16e."

[[4]]
[1] "ANTHONE (Armand)"      "1908"                  "né à Paris."           "4, avenue Victor-Hugo" "Rue des Tournelles"

[[5]]
[1] "ANTRAL (Jean)" "1920"
```

Hope this helps or leads to better ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. Thank @Kliron for your proposal (which is beyond my humble abilities).  
I completed my initiale question with a bigger sample and i I detailed my goals.